# JOOQ non utf8 encoding issue

Tags: java, jooq

Is there way to specify which encoding to use for generating sql queries from  JOOQ? We have oracle database with non UTF-8 encoding, and generated query for equal string condition contains UTF-8 chars

Comment: Do you mean the SQL string (including string literals), or the bind variables?

Comment: bind variables, in output log we see value in UTF8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, jOOQ does not touch your bind variables - they are passed on to the JDBC driver in the way you enter them in a query. So, if your `String` bind variables are encoded in UTF-8, that's how they're sent to the database:

```
COMMENTs.TEXT.eq("Schei� encoding");
```

If the encoding that you're passing to jOOQ is not the encoding that you'd like to have in your database, you have at least the following options to fix this:

#### Fix the original encoding

Of course, that should be your top priority. If UTF-8 is *generally* the wrong encoding, you should fix that in your application already. For instance, your JVM might be running with the wrong default encoding, or you have parsed some external source with the wrong encoding. The default encoding can be set with a JVM flag:

```
-Dfile.encoding=utf8
```

#### Fix the encoding when passing it to jOOQ

If the encoding is only wrong in one or two cases, you could fix it by converting it prior to passing the string to jOOQ. E.g.

```
COMMENTs.TEXT.eq(new String("Schei� encoding".getBytes(), "ISO 8859-1"));
```

This should be done only occasionally, as a quick fix.

#### Convert strings using jOOQ Converters

If the application-side encoding is correct, and you really want to convert all string values prior to passing them to Oracle JDBC, you can use a [`Converter`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/) or a data type [`Binding`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) to convert all strings from UTF-8 to your encoding. For instance:

```
public class CharsetConverter implements Converter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String from(String databaseObject) {
        return databaseObject == null ? null : 
            new String(databaseObject.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    @Override
    public String to(String userObject) {
        return userObject == null ? null : 
            new String(userObject.getBytes(), "ISO 8859-1"));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> fromType() { return String.class; }

    @Override
    public Class<String> toType() { return String.class; }
}
```